# text-align: center; not working for Inputfields Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text-align

I've got the following code that will allow the user to type the text from `center`. But when I edit the textbox with some text, the cursor moves to the right end for every character pressed. I'm using `bootstrap 2.x`, how do I fix it?

```
<input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" style="text-align: center;">
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mrght049)

Comment: Please provide some screenshots describing your issue or any additional information. From your explanation, that sounds as the correct behaviour.

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: i guess its working fine https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17604/.. in particular which browser its not working?

Comment: The js fiddle by G.L.P is using Bootstrap 3, should be 2.x. Here is a working example using Bootstrap 2 https://jsfiddle.net/mrght049/

Comment: The code provided works with bootstrap 2.x as is. You must add something else that changes the behavior/rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the inline style and use text-center class instead :

```
<input type="text" class="input-xxlarge text-center" >
```